# thie laravel install homestead,vagrant up fail

Tags: laravel, vagrant

After installing homestead, I found that I could not start by vagrant up.
my ip address segment is 192.168.10.0

Error Message:

The specified host network collides with a non-hostonly network!

This will cause your specified IP to be inaccessible. Please change

the IP or name of your host only network so that it no longer matches that of
a bridged or non-hostonly network.

Bridged Network Address: '192.168.10.0'

Host-only Network 'Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller': '192.168.10.0'

Answer (score 0):

IP should be '**192.168.10.10**'

Answer (score 0):

This means that the IP address `192.168.10.10` which homestead tries to use by default is already in use on your network. Open the `Homestead.yaml` file in the Homestead directory (usually `~/Homestead` or `C:/Users/<you>/Homestead`) and change `ip` to another `192.168` address e.g. `192.168.99.99`.

Make sure to change the IP address in your `hosts` file to this IP too if you use that.